# Counting letters with python

Tags: python, string

What I am trying to do is count how many times each letter appear in a string. The I want to store the details in a dictionary.
The following is my attempt to do so:

```
def scan(string):
    list_string = []
    for letter in string:
         list_string.append(letter)

    list_string.sort()
    scanned = {}

    for k in range(0,len(list_string)):
        count = 0
        for kk in range(k,len(list_string)):
            if list_string[k] == list_string[kk]:
                count += 1

        scanned.update({list_string[k]:count})

    return scanned
```

However every key is having the value 1 even though there are times when a letter appears more than one time.

It works fine when I try this

```
print("Letter '{}': \t {}.format(list_string[k],count))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

letter_count = Counter(mystring)
```

Answer (score 7):

## Easy fix

You can simply count with the `Counter`:

```
from collection import Counter

ctr = Counter(list_string)
```

Now `ctr` is a `Counter`: a special sort of dictionary. It maps the elements that were in the list onto numbers (the amount of time it is in the list). An element that has not been seen, is mapped on 0.

## The error

That's because you **overwrite** it each time you recount that value.

Say the list is:

```
['a','b','a','a']
```

Now you first set the `k`-cursor (`^`) to the first element, and the `kk`-cursor (`v`) to the same:

```
#v
['a','b','a','a']
#^
```

Now we count the number of `a`s and obtain 3. Next we advance, the `k`-counter and count the number of `b`s (1). Now the cursor is moved again, to the second `a`:

```
#        v
['a','b','a','a']
#        ^
```

Now we count the number of `'a'`s again, but now we obtain 2: because the `kk`-cursor ignores the first one. Finally we move the cursor to the last `'a'`, and count the number of `'a'`s, and guess what? We obtain 1. So we rewrite it to 1.

```
#            v
['a','b','a','a']
#            ^
```

Regardless of the number of times an element occurs in the list, we will always count it a *last* time, and then the count will obviously always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
letter_count = { x : list(mystring).count(x) for x in set(mystring)}
```

As rightly pointed out, a pretty pythonic one liner with bad asymptotic complexity **if your elements are hashable**, in which case using count(...) will become a linear operation.

Comment: Don't use `count(..)` for things that are hashable. It turns an *O(n)* algorithm into an *O(n^2)* algorithm.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmm, you're right... incrementing default dict inside a loop would be better.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, because it works **given the elements are not hashable**. So it has *added value*. But you better mention this in the answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks! I appreciate it. Updated my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Comment: @ElektronAtom The answers above are really good. I recommend you accept one of them. :)